# How to create XML file by SQL query?

Tags: asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a `Select` query which selects the top 10 values from table

```
Create proc [dbo].[SP_Select_Top10]
as
   select DISTINCT top (10)
       Score, FBid 
   from 
       FB_Player 
   ORDER BY 
       Score DESC
```

What I need is to have the results of this query in **xml** file as.

```
<player>
    <name> </name>
    <score> </score>
</player>
```

I use ASP.NET to create this file how can I do that ?

Comment: Check out the docu on `FOR XML PATH`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your stored procedure like this - use the `FOR XML PATH(), ROOT()` syntax to have SQL Server generate a proper XML for you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procGetPlayerScore
AS BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10)
        ID AS '@ID',   -- creates an attribute on the <Player> node
        Name,          -- gets output as element inside <Player>
        Score          -- gets output as element inside <Player>
    FROM 
        dbo.FB_Players
    ORDER BY 
        Score DESC 
    FOR XML PATH('Player'), ROOT('AllPlayers')
END
```

In your C# code, you need something like this - connect to the database, execute the stored procedure, get back the single row, single column of that stored procedure (the XML produced):

```
// set up SQL Server connection and command to execute the stored procedure
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=test;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
using (SqlCommand cmdGetPlayers = new SqlCommand("dbo.procGetPlayerScore", conn)) 
{
     // define that it's a stored procedure
     cmdGetPlayers.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     // open connection, execute procedure, get resulting XML, close connection
     conn.Open();
     string playersXml = cmdGetPlayers.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     conn.Close();
}
```

As result, you'll get a XML something like this:

```
<AllPlayers>
    <Player ID="4">
        <Name>Player 4</Name>
        <Score>72.1500</Score>
    </Player>
    <Player ID="1">
        <Name>Player 1</Name>
        <Score>50.5000</Score>
    </Player>
    ......
</AllPlayers>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the native XML options of SQL Server

[Link here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

Also please note

```
<player>
<playername="" score="" />
</player>
```

is not valid xml, it would have to something like

```
<player name="" score="" />
```

or

```
<player>
    <name></name>
    <score></score>
</player>
```

depending on whether you want to be element-centric or attribute-centric, but all of these can be specified in the SQL server XML output options. Then you could just get the ASP.NET side to save the resulting query as a file.